# Error in Creating Views in Fragment

Tags: java, android, eclipse, fragment

I have created a Activity with 3 Fragment layout where the user will swipe the screen to display another fragment.

On my first fragment I plan to have a ListView to display out the information of the user.
However the codes I normally used for the extends Activity do not work with extends Fragment. 
I researched a little and finally got rid of the red lines but my app crashes when I display the fragment.

Here is my code:

```
public class LayoutOne extends ListFragment {
ListView myInfoList;
String[] items = {"Item 1", "Item 2"};
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter;

public static Fragment newInstance(Context context) {
    LayoutOne f = new LayoutOne();  

    return f;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_one, container, false);    

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    myInfoList = getListView();
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);
    myInfoList.setAdapter(adapter);
}


}
```

And here is my log cat:

> 06-16 17:57:16.150: D/AndroidRuntime(20378): Shutting down VM
>   06-16 17:57:16.150: W/dalvikvm(20378): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40ff9930)
>   06-16 17:57:16.158: E/AndroidRuntime(20378): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   06-16 17:57:16.158: E/AndroidRuntime(20378): java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
>   06-16 17:57:16.158: E/AndroidRuntime(20378):   at android.support.v4.app.ListFragment.ensureList(ListFragment.java:344)
>   06-16 17:57:16.158: E/AndroidRuntime(20378):   at android.support.v4.app.ListFragment.onViewCreated(ListFragment.java:145)
>   06-16 17:57:16.158: E/AndroidRuntime(20378):   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:884)
>   06-16 17:57:16.158: E/AndroidRuntime(20378):   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1080)
>   06-16 17:57:16.158: E/AndroidRuntime(20378):   at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:622)
>   06-16 17:57:16.158: E/AndroidRuntime(20378):   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1416)
>   06-16 17:57:16.158: E/AndroidRuntime(20378):   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:431)
>   06-16 17:57:16.158: E/AndroidRuntime(20378):   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:139)
>   06-16 17:57:16.158: E/AndroidRuntime(20378):   at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:804)
>   06-16 17:57:16.158: E/AndroidRuntime(20378):   at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1016)
>   06-16 17:57:16.158: E/AndroidRuntime(20378):   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15523)
>   06-16 17:57:16.158: E/AndroidRuntime(20378):   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
>   06-16 17:57:16.158: E/AndroidRuntime(20378):   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
>   06-16 17:57:16.158: E/AndroidRuntime(20378):   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
>   06-16 17:57:16.158: E/AndroidRuntime(20378):   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
>   06-16 17:57:16.158: E/AndroidRuntime(20378):   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15523)
>   06-16 17:57:16.158: E/AndroidRuntime(20378):   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
>   06-16 17:57:16.158: E/AndroidRuntime(20378):   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
>   06-16 17:57:16.158: E/AndroidRuntime(20378):   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15523)
>   06-16 17:57:16.158: E/AndroidRuntime(20378):   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:847)
>   06-16 17:57:16.158: E/AndroidRuntime(20378):   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
>   06-16 17:57:16.158: E/AndroidRuntime(20378):   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15523)
>   06-16 17:57:16.158: E/AndroidRuntime(20378):   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
>   06-16 17:57:16.158: E/AndroidRuntime(20378):   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
>   06-16 17:57:16.158: E/AndroidRuntime(20378):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2434)
>   06-16 17:57:16.158: E/AndroidRuntime(20378):   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15523)
>   06-16 17:57:16.158: E/AndroidRuntime(20378):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1874)
>   06-16 17:57:16.158: E/AndroidRuntime(20378):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1089)
>   06-16 17:57:16.158: E/AndroidRuntime(20378):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1265)
>   06-16 17:57:16.158: E/AndroidRuntime(20378):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:989)
>   06-16 17:57:16.158: E/AndroidRuntime(20378):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4351)
>   06-16 17:57:16.158: E/AndroidRuntime(20378):   at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
>   06-16 17:57:16.158: E/AndroidRuntime(20378):   at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
>   06-16 17:57:16.158: E/AndroidRuntime(20378):   at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
>   06-16 17:57:16.158: E/AndroidRuntime(20378):   at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
>   06-16 17:57:16.158: E/AndroidRuntime(20378):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
>   06-16 17:57:16.158: E/AndroidRuntime(20378):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>   06-16 17:57:16.158: E/AndroidRuntime(20378):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>   06-16 17:57:16.158: E/AndroidRuntime(20378):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5233)
>   06-16 17:57:16.158: E/AndroidRuntime(20378):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   06-16 17:57:16.158: E/AndroidRuntime(20378):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>   06-16 17:57:16.158: E/AndroidRuntime(20378):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:799)
>   06-16 17:57:16.158: E/AndroidRuntime(20378):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:566)
>   06-16 17:57:16.158: E/AndroidRuntime(20378):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: Have you tried to inflate and return a View instead of a ViewGroup?

Comment: yes, just tried it. Crashed too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you never initialize `myInfoList`. Ihmo your class should extends ListFragment instead of Fragment.

your onCreateView should inflate the layout that contains a ListView and you should move

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);
myInfoList.setAdapter(adapter);
```

inside onActivityCreate:

```
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    myInfoList = getListView();
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);
    myInfoList.setAdapter(adapter); 
}
```

the id for your ListView has to be

```
android:id="@id/android:list"
```

Comment: I edited the codes but it still crashes.
I'll edit the main thread now

Comment: @BloopieBloops post the changes and the logcat

Comment: posted, changing the id to list now

Comment: @BloopieBloops , so you fixed or still you have issue?

Comment: the id fixed it! thanks a bunch!
Just a few questions, What is the difference if i extend ListFragment, Activity, etc..

Also do i put any codes in onActivityCreated?

Comment: @BloopieBloops the Fragment and ListFragment documetation covers this topic. You should read it